# how to search character in list of array object inside an array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, javascript-objects

I have an array

```
0: key: "001" value: Array(1) 0: Id: "2345" Name: "Test"
1: key: "112" value: Array(2) 0: Id: "1234" Name: "UHV" 1: Id: "3424" Name: "ABC"
2: key: "222" value: Array(3) 0: Id: "2312" Name: "ABD" 1: Id: "1321" Name: "RFV" 2: Id: "4567" Name: "ERF"
```

when i try to Search with 'AB' my logic should search my array object and return . please help me for the logic

```
1: key: "112" value: Array(1) 0: Id: "3424" Name: "ABC"
2: key: "222" value: Array(1) 0: Id: "2312" Name: "ABD"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First you given JSON Array is wrong. I corrected it based on assumption:**

```
var arr =[
 {"key": "001", "value":[{ "Id": "2345", "Name": "Test"}]},
 {"key": "112", "value": [{"Id": "1234" ,"Name": "UHV"} ,{ "Id": "3424" ,"Name": "ABC"}]},
 {"key": "222", "value":  [{"Id": "2312" ,"Name": "ABD"} ,{ "Id": "1321", "Name": "RFV"} ,{"Id": "4567" ,"Name": "ERF"}]}
 ];
```

**Secondly, you can achieve this via using Array `inclues()` and `reduce()`**

**Refer to the below code for reference:**

```js
var arr =[
 {"key": "001", "value":[{ "Id": "2345", "Name": "Test"}]},
 {"key": "112", "value": [{"Id": "1234" ,"Name": "UHV"} ,{ "Id": "3424" ,"Name": "ABC"}]},
 {"key": "222", "value":  [{"Id": "2312" ,"Name": "ABD"} ,{ "Id": "1321", "Name": "RFV"} ,{"Id": "4567" ,"Name": "ERF"}]}
 ];
 
 function filterValues(arr) {
    const filtered = arr.reduce((arr, {value, ...item}) => {
    const filteredValue = value.filter(item => item.Name.includes('AB'));
    filteredValue.length && arr.push({...item, value: filteredValue});
    return arr;
    }, []);

  return filtered;
}

console.log(filterValues(arr))
```

Comment: the OP wants only the found items in `value` in the result...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array::filter()` to find `AB` Name in `value` with `String::includes()` and compose the root filtered array with `Array::reduce()`. The filtered `value` array items are composed with spread and destructuring syntax:

```js
const arr =[
 {"key": "001", "value":[{ "Id": "2345", "Name": "Test"}]},
 {"key": "112", "value": [{"Id": "1234" ,"Name": "UHV"} ,{ "Id": "3424" ,"Name": "ABC"}]},
 {"key": "222", "value":  [{"Id": "2312" ,"Name": "ABD"} ,{ "Id": "1321", "Name": "RFV"} ,{"Id": "4567" ,"Name": "ERF"}]}
 ];
 
const filtered = arr.reduce((arr, {value, ...item}) => {
   const found = value.filter(item => item.Name.includes('AB'));
   found.length && arr.push({...item, value: found});
   return arr;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered));
```

Answer (score -1):

**here are three simple examples of how you can filter the array based on your criteria**

1. (Using filter and some):

```
    const arr = [
  {"key": "001", "value": [{"Id": "2345", "Name": "Test"}]},
  {"key": "112", "value": [{"Id": "1234", "Name": "UHV"}, {"Id": "3424", "Name": "ABC"}]},
  {"key": "222", "value": [{"Id": "2312", "Name": "ABD"}, {"Id": "1321", "Name": "RFV"}, {"Id": "4567", "Name": "ERF"}]}
];

function filterValues(arr) {
  const filteredValues = arr.filter(item => {
    if (Array.isArray(item.value)) {
      return item.value.some(innerItem => innerItem.Name.includes("AB"));
    }
    return false;
  });

  return filteredValues;
}

console.log(filterValues(arr));
```

2. (Using reduce):

```
    const arr = [
  {"key": "001", "value": [{"Id": "2345", "Name": "Test"}]},
  {"key": "112", "value": [{"Id": "1234", "Name": "UHV"}, {"Id": "3424", "Name": "ABC"}]},
  {"key": "222", "value": [{"Id": "2312", "Name": "ABD"}, {"Id": "1321", "Name": "RFV"}, {"Id": "4567", "Name": "ERF"}]}
];

const filtered = arr.reduce((result, { value, ...item }) => {
  const found = value.filter(innerItem => innerItem.Name.includes('AB'));
  if (found.length) {
    result.push({ ...item, value: found });
  }
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(filtered);
```

3. (Using ES6 syntax and arrow functions):

```
const arr = [
  {"key": "001", "value": [{"Id": "2345", "Name": "Test"}]},
  {"key": "112", "value": [{"Id": "1234", "Name": "UHV"}, {"Id": "3424", "Name": "ABC"}]},
  {"key": "222", "value": [{"Id": "2312", "Name": "ABD"}, {"Id": "1321", "Name": "RFV"}, {"Id": "4567", "Name": "ERF"}]}
];

const filtered = arr.filter(({ value }) => value.some(({ Name }) => Name.includes('AB')));

console.log(filtered);
```

> All three examples will produce the same output:

```
[  {"key": "112", "value": [{"Id": "3424", "Name": "ABC"}]},
  {"key": "222", "value": [{"Id": "2312", "Name": "ABD"}]}
]
```